# How to create a drawable from an image in assets folder?

Tags: android, android-drawable

This code always returns null

```
String path = "file:///android_asset/image.png";
Drawable d = null;
try {
     d = Drawable.createFromStream(ContextHolder.getActivity().getAssets().open(path), null);
} catch(Exception e) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is wrong

```
String path = "image.png";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("image.png"), null);
```